# Can two sql queries affect the same row at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

In a table *example* with

```
**id**    **counter**
   1          100
```

if I execute in parallel 100 queries:

> UPDATE example SET counter = counter - 1 WHERE id = 1;

Will the final counter of that row be always 0?
Is there any need to lock the table?

Comment: Read about transactions.

Comment: I don't see the point of the transactions here, why do you suggest them?

Comment: Database guarantees [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)itiy; which pretty much means the result will be zero.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought I know but It's currently not happening to me, of course, the problem will be in my code. But it made me doubt this :P

Comment: @vivoconunxino jarlh suggested reading about transaction, because even a single statement **is** a transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the mysql documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-locking.html

> MySQL grants table write locks as follows:
>
> If there are no locks on the table, put a write lock on it.
>
> Otherwise, put the lock request in the write lock queue.

So the 2 updates will go happen sequentialy